# How to use ActiveModel::EachValidator in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.1

How to validate specific attribute using `ActiveModel::EachValidator`.
I have written the below snippet of code. This validation will not call on saving or validating object.

```
class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
    def validate_each(record,attribute,value)
       # Logic to check email is valid or not
    end
end
```

This will work with rails 3.

Comment: I have tried to solve this but this will not invoke. Posted a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49230085/how-to-use-activemodeleachvalidator-in-rails-5 please check.

Comment: Did you called Email Validator from your controller ?

Comment: No. I not calling it from anywhere. In rails 3 it will invoke automatically on saving or validating object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A simple base class that can be used along with ActiveModel::Validations::ClassMethods#validates_with**

```
class User
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  validates_with EmailValidator
end

class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
     # Logic to check email is valid or not
     record.errors.add :email, "This is some complex validation"
  end
end
```

Any class that inherits from ActiveModel::Validator must implement a method called validate which accepts a record.

To cause a validation error, you must add to the record's errors directly from within the validators message.

For more details you can check [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validator.html).

If you are looking for only email validation then you can try this.

```
class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attr_name, value)
    unless value =~ /^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i
      record.errors.add(attr_name, :email, options.merge(:value => value))
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `ActiveModel::Validator` is working for me too. I m getting struggle in validating `ActiveModel::EachValidator` as just want validate email not whole object.

Comment: Checkout my last comment.

Answer (score 3):

You can put your `EmailValidator` class inside the `models/concerns` directory. Then inside your model you can validate the email attribute using the example below.

```
 class User < ApplicationRecord
   validates :email, presence: true, email: true
 end
```

Rails will look for the `EmailValidator`class within the scope when it encounters `email: true` then validate the attribute using the `validate_each` method.

Comment: Does this work as a naming convention? For example would it work if it was called `FooValidator` and then `validates :email, presence: true, foo: true`?

Comment: @Tashows yes the naming convention requires that it ends with `Validator` such that you can then do `foo: true`

Comment: yes I realized after doing some tests. Ended up heavily using this. Very useful! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon this question when searching for custom validators defined outside the model where they are used requiring namespace to be specified (in case you need to reuse this validator across other models).

imagine the following folder structure

```bash
| models
  - user.rb
  | validators
    - email_validator.rb
```

and `email_validator.rb` contents are

```rb
class Validators::EmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
    def validate_each(record,attribute,value)
       # Logic to check email is valid or not
    end
end
```

and then in your `User` model (or any other model) you have to specify namespace in order to use it.

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  validates :email, presence: true, 'validators/email': true
end
```